# Opening a file in a running instance of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, explorer, windows-messages

When I tell Explorer to open a file in Visual Studio 2017, then the file will be opened in a running instance of Visual Studio. Only if Visual Studio is not running, a new instance is started.

I'd like to know how this is achieved, and I can think of two scenarios:

- Do they use something like .NET Remoting? Like, Explorer starts a new instance of `devenv.exe`, this process checks if there is already a running `devenv.exe` process. If there is, it signals the running process to open the file and exits.
- Or is there a Windows Message to signal a running process to open a file (something like `WM_OPEN_FILE`)? If there is, Explorer could send such a message to the main message queue of Visual Studio. This scenario could be used by other applications as well.

Or is there a third option?

Comment: VS uses an ancient out-of-process communication protocol named DDE.  It completely disappeared as a useful way to do process interop, don't make the mistake of trying to use it yourself, but is still supported by Explorer.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Data_Exchange  Your first bullet is the most accurate mental model.